# Bring data in from the infowindow on Fusion Tables layers on a Google map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables, infowindow

I'm building my first Fusion Tables, and bringing two Fusion Tables into a Google Map - one of polygons and one of points.  Instead of displaying the regular info window when you click on a polygon or a point, I want to pull some data in from the Fusion Table, but it's failing to work:

```
<script>
  function initialize() {
    var england = new google.maps.LatLng(53.2, -2);
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      center: england,
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    layer1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      query: {select: 'geometry', from: '1HgGUc72F2Wlp6dvy4GWvLyWrl1kC6aJhnM7jPyc'},
      styles: [
        { where: "Score = 0", polygonOptions: { fillColor: "#cdcdcd", fillOpacity: 0.3 } },
        { where: "Score = 1", polygonOptions: { fillColor: "#FF0000", fillOpacity: 0.5 } },
        { where: "Score = 2", polygonOptions: { fillColor: "#FF7E00", fillOpacity: 0.5 } },
        { where: "Score = 3", polygonOptions: { fillColor: "#008000", fillOpacity: 0.5 } }],
    options: {suppressInfoWindows: true},
    map: map,
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(layer1, 'click', function(e) {e.infoWindowHtml = "Score" + e.row['Score'].value;}
    });

    layer2 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {select: 'postcode', from: '1bawAKwQAUGE4mzYSyw4lTbOcgp7MgIGOLROel8Y'},
    options: {suppressInfoWindows: true},
    map: map,
     });
    google.maps.event.addListener(layer2, 'click', function(e) {e.infoWindowHtml = "Postcode" + e.row['Postcode'].value;}
    });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  }
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[It was all working well](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4086051/epilepsyaction/critical-time-maps/sun-1746.html), infowindows suppressed, until I added the AddListener and addDomListeners. Can anyone help me get back on track, please?

Comment: You will not have much success with your attempt.

When you click on a point, the click will not pass the click-event to the underlying polygon-layer(and AFAIK there is no way to change this).

This will never work as long as there isn't any relation between the two tables, because without this relation there isn't even a chance to request both tables by a given coordinate.

Answer (score 2):

1. You have syntax errors in your "new" code (two extra "}")
2. You have your call to addDomListener inside your initialize function (shouldn't matter as you still have it in the `<body` tag, but you really shouldn't have it both places.

   ```
   <script>
    function initialize() {
    var england = new google.maps.LatLng(53.2, -2);
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
     center: england,
     zoom: 8,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   });

   layer1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
     query: {select: 'geometry', from: '1HgGUc72F2Wlp6dvy4GWvLyWrl1kC6aJhnM7jPyc'},
     styles: [
       { where: "Score = 0", polygonOptions: { fillColor: "#cdcdcd", fillOpacity: 0.3 } },
       { where: "Score = 1", polygonOptions: { fillColor: "#FF0000", fillOpacity: 0.5 } },
       { where: "Score = 2", polygonOptions: { fillColor: "#FF7E00", fillOpacity: 0.5 } },
       { where: "Score = 3", polygonOptions: { fillColor: "#008000", fillOpacity: 0.5 } }],
   options: {suppressInfoWindows: true},
   map: map,
   });
   google.maps.event.addListener(layer1, 'click', function(e) {e.infoWindowHtml = "Score" + e.row['Score'].value;});
   layer2 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
   query: {select: 'postcode', from: '1bawAKwQAUGE4mzYSyw4lTbOcgp7MgIGOLROel8Y'},
   options: {suppressInfoWindows: true},
   map: map,
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(layer2, 'click', function(e) {e.infoWindowHtml = "Postcode" + e.row['Postcode'].value;});
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
    </head>
     <body>
      <div id="map_canvas"></div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTablesLayer_epilepsyaction_critical-time-SOquestionA.html)
modified to make the infowindows from each layer work, using this function:

```
function openIW(FTevent) {
  // infoWindow.setContent(FTevent.infoWindowHtml);
  // infoWindow.setPosition(FTevent.latLng);
  infoWindow.setOptions(
    { 
     content: FTevent.infoWindowHtml,
     position: FTevent.latLng,
     pixelOffset: FTevent.pixelOffset
    });
  infoWindow.open(map);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for that geocodezip.  I should have emphasised the word *some* in my original posting.  What I was wanting to do was only bring over *some* of the fields from the Fusion Tables - obviously, different fields for the two layers/tables.  That's why I had separate addListener/addDomListener for each layer (even if that was wrong!).

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  I am not a mind reader, I can't tell which parts of the data you want and which you don't.  You can certainly change the provided code to do whatever you want, it is just an example/proof of concept.

Comment: Thanks for the example/proof of concept.  Say if I wanted to import one variable (a different variable from each layer) and add that to the info window.  I've duplicated openIW for each layer and tried to do the following:

`function openIW1(FTevent) {
  // infoWindow.setContent(FTevent.infoWindowHtml);
  // infoWindow.setPosition(FTevent.latLng);
  infoWindow.setOptions(
    { 
     content: 'Score: ' + e.row['Score'].value,
     position: FTevent.latLng,
     pixelOffset: FTevent.pixelOffset
    });
  infoWindow.open(map);
}`

But I'm not getting anything now when I click on the map.

Comment: Look at the javascript console.  I get "e is not defined". Fix that.

Answer (score 0):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function(e) {
    console.log("E.Row! : "+ e.row['name'].value);
});
```